# Exception in async methods is not caught

Tags: c#, asynchronous, cancellation

The following code does not catch my OperationCancelException which is thrown by calling `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`.

```
public partial class TitleWindow : Window, IAsyncInitialization
{
    public Task Initialization{get; private set;}
    CancellationTokenSource cts;

    public TitleWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            cts.Cancel();
            Initialization = GetCancelExceptionAsync(cts.Token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Operation canceled!");
        }
    }

    public async Task GetCancelExceptionAsync(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}
```

However if i replace my `Window_Loaded` method with the following (making it async and await the call of my async method), the exception gets caught.

```
private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        await GetCancelExceptionAsync(cts.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Operation canceled!");
    }
}
```

Why is my first approach not working? Is the exception not properly propagated to the correct synchronization context?

I was trying to use `The Asynchronous Initialization Pattern` described in [Stephen Clearys blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) to be able to later on await a task which was started in a constructor (and in order to make it comparable to my second example I used the (`async`) `Window_Loaded` event to await methods there right away, like suggested to me in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606556/async-await-am-i-using-the-wrong-synchronisation-context)). Then I wanted to provide an option to cancel the async method that I started in the constructor, where i am currently stuck because the exception handling does not work as I expected.

With my "non-working" code, I can catch the exception by putting `await Initialization` in a try-catch block somewhere, but I still get an additional unhandled exception.

How do I implement this in a way that allows me to await my async method later on (to ensure that I do not work with an inconsistent state of my object) and still being able to cancel that long-running Task (which would of course need to return/set default values)?

Comment: If you do not await the task, execution has left the try/catch well before the exception is thrown. The await turns the rest of the method into a continuation so that it can be executed when the task completes.

Comment: Problem lies in the fact that if you do not await the Task in your Try-block, when it finishes, it'll be outside the try-scope. Meaning that it wont catch it. What you would probably do is use the 'ContinueWith' on the Task. It takes 1 parameter, namely the Task. And you can then grab the Task.Exception property and use it however

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example the exception is not caught because it does not occure before leaving the `try/catch` block. If you want to catch it there you need to wait/`await` it there exactly like you do in the second example.
If you do not await the returned task the method continues execution and leaves the `try/catch` block before the exception actually occures...

If you want to catch the exception "out of band" you can also register to `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` (this event is called if a task is throwing an exception which is nowhere caught) to get all uncaught exceptions or monitor the tasks [`Exception`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception(v=vs.110).aspx) property. May also check out [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12981091/472434) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Exeption is thrown in the task on another thread.

```
public async Task GetCancelExceptionAsync(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // your Cancleation expeption
            }
        }
```